# Sidebar not covering full page on window resize

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a website. And I'm trying to fix the layout but I'm having some issues. The side bar doesn't cover the full screen on resize and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Website looks like this on full page (it works fine on full page):

[image: Website on full page]

But when resizing looks like this:

[image: Website resized]

[image: website resized]

On resizing i can scroll up and down and also left and right and I don't want that also.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  line-height: inherit
}

#container {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

#navbar {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 18rem;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

#right-side {
  width: 100%;
}

#banner {
  height: 8rem;
  width: 100%;
}

#content {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">

  <navbar id="navbar">
    <div id="logo">
      Logo Image + Text
    </div>
    <div id="navigation">
      Navigation
    </div>
    <div id="social-links">
      Social media links
    </div>
  </navbar>

  <div id="right-side">
    <div id="banner">
      Page banner
    </div>
    <div id="content">
      Content
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: I created a snippet from the code you provided. I can't see the issue you described in your post. Please add enough code so we can reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it concern with your problem, but you have already set this meta tag in the head of your web page?

```
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  //other meta tag
</head>
```

Comment: Yep, I do have it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you didn't share the whole css code, but in my opinion, the `#navbar` is full height and transparent. The logo, navigation and social-links divs have their own background color right? In this case you could use the `justify-content` for it like this:

```css
#navbar {
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
   width: 18rem;
   min-height: 100vh;
   justify-content: space-between;
}
```

Comment: They do have their own background color. It's the full code almost. I've not shared the css for #logo, #navigation and #social-links. But i'm not sure how that influences the layout. Also adding justify-content: space-between doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Then I think @5c4r10 answer could help you

Comment: I already have that in the head of my page.